Bluetooth process is active BUT does not work in Ubuntu 22.04 :(
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
 bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-08-07 23:48:32 CEST; 4min 42s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 5602 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 13944)
     Memory: 656.0K
        CPU: 49ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─5602 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

ago 07 23:48:32 GarPakh systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
ago 07 23:48:32 GarPakh bluetoothd[5602]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
ago 07 23:48:32 GarPakh systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
ago 07 23:48:32 GarPakh bluetoothd[5602]: Starting SDP server
ago 07 23:48:32 GarPakh bluetoothd[5602]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized

but bluetooth is still off:


Please edit to add results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
